# VS2008 C++ lib project property setting problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, wizard

I created a C++ static library project in VS2008 using the wizard as following:

> -Win32 application
>
> -In "Application Settings", selected "Static Library"
>
> -**unchecked** "Precompiled Header"

After it completed, I found that under "Project Properties->Configuration Properties", there is no "C/C++" section. I tried to create another static library project with the "Precompiled Header" option **checked** and the "C/C++" section shows up.

Could somebody tell me why?
Does it mean that without using "Precompiled Header", all other settings in "C/C++" section, like "Additional include directories", are not useful at all? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"C\C++" section is presented only if you have any c\c++ files added to the project. In opposite case this section is useless because your library is not C\C++ library

Comment: Yes, there was no file when I created the project. But after I added C++ file in this lib project, there is still no C\C++ section shown in the project properties...

Comment: Ah ha, I only added .h file before, after added .cpp file, the "C\C++" section shown up! Thanks a lot, Andy

Comment: if you think my answer is helpful - you can accept it and/or upvote it, it's StackOverflow (SO) way to thank

Comment: One thing I still don't understand: I have specified to create a "Visual C++" project in the wizard then why VS still needs a .cpp file to show the C/C++ section?

Comment: @rob: most probably just because of internal implementation architecture. I agree it's quite confusing, just tried to guess an author reasoning

Answer (score 0):

The "precompiled header" section does not influence that. Maybe you had the solution selected in the Project Explorer. Try creating a new project with precompiled headers unchecked, be sure to have the Project selected when you open the properties.